# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have found a lot of questions related to this, but not still able to over come mine. `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class fragment`

My question is does the case differ with **#91**? Because no body has ever asked with this(**though other questions have #20, #2, #11**). Or this is just like indicating line number in .java?. Let me know if I have to provide some more details.

**P.S.:** I get this error, when I swipe the pages of ViewPager but only at second round.
Thank you

**My complete logcat**

```
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class fragment
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at com.example.fragments.Recommend.onCreateView(Recommend.java:47)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1291)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12862)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:704)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12862)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12862)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12862)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2125)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12862)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:573)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #91: Duplicate id 0x7f080087, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-19 07:32:24.080: E/AndroidRuntime(15498):    ... 37 more
```

**QUESTION**: WHY ERROR AFTER FIRST ROUND OF SWIPING FRAGMENTS? WHY NOT AT FIRST?

Comment: Binary XML file line **#91**. so yes it indicate the line nmber in your xml file.

Comment: Posting the XML file would be useful. Yes, you have a problem with line 91 of your XML file.

Comment: @Squonk i have alot of them, which one should i?

Comment: post xml file that has the error!!

Comment: @mmlooloo I don't know which one has error. Can you figure out from the logcat that i have posted?

Comment: post the one that has a fragment layout?

Comment: and also look at `Duplicate id 0x7f080087`!!

Comment: @mmlooloo Thank you every one for guiding me. I fixed my problem. Should I post my answer?

Comment: what is that? Duplicate id or null tag?

Comment: @mmlooloo duplicate id and another one too. please refer my answer below

Comment: @Squonk Please refer to my solution below and explain how this overcomes " You shouldn't be inflating fragments inside other fragments. From Android's documentation:

    Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had two problems.
 **Problem 1:**

I had same name for map in 2 fragments. I changed it to different

**Problem 2:** Major one.

I added this code into my fragment

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = (fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mapz1));
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

This code creats a map fragment programmatically and initializes the map.